# JAXB @XmlAdapter for arbitrary XML

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, dom, jaxb

I have a `org.w3c.dom.Element` that I'm returning from my `XmlAdapter` for a custom `@XmlElement` and I'd like to include it as part of a JAXB object as arbitrary XML (I'm aware I'll have to hand-craft the XSD). However, JAXB complains with

```
org.w3c.dom.Element is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
```

Apparently the w3c XML types are [not supported as Java types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html#wp230880table221487), which is a shame. But further than this, I get the same error when I use `javax.xml.transform.Result` which is apparently supported.

**How can I include arbitrary XML elements as elements in JAXB?**

Note: as per https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1668210 I've also tried

```
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
message = factory.createMessage();          
SOAPElement element = message.getSOAPBody().addDocument(doc);
```

but that is also giving the same error.

Comment: Have you looked at `@XmlAnyElement` ?

Comment: @MattR I thought that's more for the XSD mapping: you still need to hand a supported object type to JAXB for it to convert it into XML.

Comment: I've used it to unmarshal XML elements I didn't specifically model, then marshal it back to XML, so I'm guessing you could also create your own `List<Element>` annotated with `@XmlAnyElement` and it would marshal it...

Comment: @MattR that's probably because your beans met the rules described in the docs linked above (public constructor, getters/setters, all primitive types supported by JAXB).

Comment: So no part of your bean is valid? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your requirement, can you show some code?

Comment: @MattR I am using an `XmlAdapter`, so I am providing my own way to convert my (non-compliant) objects into objects that JAXB can understand. I can create the raw XML myself, as an `Element` or `Source`, but JAXB doesn't want to accept it. Sorry, code is proprietary.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with a simple example (with the proprietary information removed)?

Comment: @DannyMo recreation is pretty trivial, but exceptionally verbose. Just create an `@XmlAdapter` that has `Element` or `Source` as the return type for `marshal`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can have an `XmlAdapter` that converts you domain object to an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Element` as long as you specify the value type as `Object` (not `Element`).

---

Below is a full example.

### XmlAdapter

A field/property of type `java.lang.Object` will keep unknown content as DOM nodes.  You can leverage this in your use case by specifying the value type in your `XmlAdapter` as `Object`.  You will need to ensure that the root element returned from the `marshal` method matches the field/property as defined by the `@XmlElement` annotation.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class BarAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Bar>{

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    public BarAdapter() {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // TODO - Handle Exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Bar unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        Element element = (Element) v;
        bar.value = element.getTextContent();
        return bar;
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(Bar v) throws Exception {
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        Element root = document.createElement("bar");
        root.setTextContent(v.value);
        return root;
    }

}
```

### Java Model

**Foo**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to reference the `XmlAdapter`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BarAdapter.class)
    private Bar bar;

}
```

**Bar**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {

    String value;

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Since there is a cost to creating the DocumentBuilderFactory we can leverage JAXB's ability to handle stateful instances of XmlAdapter by setting an instance on the Marshaller.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18272059/input.xml");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAdapter(new BarAdapter());
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar>Hello World</bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: that was a bit verbose to say that all I need to do is change my `@XmlAdapter` signature from `Element` to `Object` :-P I will try this when I'm at the code and get back to you, thanks!