# JAXB marshalling boolean into a complex type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, boolean, marshalling

I am new in JAXB and I would like to do something i don't know if it's doable. I have a java class to marshall like this :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XMLAccessType.NONE)
public class MyClass {
  @XmlElement
  private String a = "x";
  @XmlElement
  private String b = "xx";
  @XmlElement
  private boolean c = true;
  ...
}
```

and want XML output like this :

```
<?xml ...?>
<MyClass>
    <a>x</a>
    <b>xx</b>
    <c value="true"/>
</MyClass>
```

One solution i have in mind is to use a boolean wrapper class to make it work, but i would like to avoid this as it takes me away the ability to use boolean primitive true, false.

Can we do that in JAXB?

Comment: After searching around ("jaxb flattened element" and related) I suspect this can be done with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272059/jaxb-xmladapter-for-arbitrary-xml), but I don't know enough about JAXB to be certain, so I'm giving this suggestion as a comment rather than answer.

Comment: @bkail - Here is how the `XmlAdapter` approach would look:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27551339/383861

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Leverage An `XmlAdapter`

You could create an `XmlAdapter` to get the behaviour you are looking for. An `XmlAdapter` converts a domain object into another type for the purposes of marshalling and unmarshalling.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class BooleanAdapter extends XmlAdapter<BooleanAdapter.AdaptedBoolean, Boolean> {

    public static class AdaptedBoolean {

        @XmlAttribute
        public boolean value;

    }

    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(AdaptedBoolean adaptedBoolean) throws Exception {
        return adaptedBoolean.value;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedBoolean marshal(Boolean v) throws Exception {
        AdaptedBoolean adaptedBoolean = new AdaptedBoolean();
        adaptedBoolean.value = v;
        return adaptedBoolean;
    }

}
```

### To Use the `XmlAdapter`

To use the `XmlAdapter` your mapped field will need to be of type `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.  You accessor methods can still be `boolean` if you want.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class MyClass {
    @XmlElement
    private String a = "x";
    @XmlElement
    private String b = "xx";

    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
    private Boolean c = true;

    public boolean getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(boolean c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i did try to use XMLAdapter but didn't know i could use it this way. I'm gonna try your solution :)

Comment: Hello, happy new year ! I tested your solution and it works fine. Thank you very much, have a good day ! ^^

Answer (score 1):

The XML output of your class is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myClass>
    <a>x</a>
    <b>xx</b>
    <c>true</c>
</myClass>
```

If you want the `boolean` value to result in

```
<c value="true" />
```

then you need a wrapper element around the `boolean c` field. This can be of type `Boolean` or some other custom type with the `boolean c` inside of it, and marked with `@XmlAttribute`.

**Example:**

```
class MyBool {
    @XmlAttribute(name="value")
    private boolean c = true;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class MyClass {
  @XmlElement
  private String a = "x";
  @XmlElement
  private String b = "xx";
  @XmlElement
  private MyBool c = new MyBool();
}
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myClass>
    <a>x</a>
    <b>xx</b>
    <c value="true"/>
</myClass>
```

### Note:

If you don't want to use a wrapper, you can still annotate `boolean c` with `@XmlAttribute` like this:

```
@XmlAttribute(name="value")
private boolean c = true;
```

But then it will be rendered as an attribute of the *wrapper* class which in this case is `MyClass`, so the output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myClass value="true">
    <a>x</a>
    <b>xx</b>
</myClass>
```

Comment: I dont want to change my boolean class because it is used in a lot of others classes and i loose the ability to use boolean like 'boolean a = true'. I'll try your solution if i can't find another one. Thanks for your reply :)