# Using JAXB to extract content of several XML elements as text

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following XML file

```
<items>
   <title><a href="blabla">blabla</a></title>
   <text><a href="123">123</a></text>
</items>
```

I'm unmarshalling the XML to the next java object by JAXB and XmlAnyElement annotation with two classes implementing DOMHandler. I want to extract the inner XML of elements "title" and "text" as Strings.

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String text;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    @XmlAnyElement(value = TitleHandler.class)
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    @XmlAnyElement(value = TextHandler.class)
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

But when i put a breakpoints in the method "String getElement(StreamResult rt)" of the TitleHandler and the TextHandler, both of elements use TextHandler.class for unmarshalling. Element "title" use TextHandler instead of TitleHandler.
Any help will be greatly appriciated

UPDATE
Restriction usage constraints for XmlAnyElement annotation:
**There can be only one XmlAnyElement annotated JavaBean property in a class and its super classes.**

Comment: Do you want the String `title` to contain `<a href="blabla">blabla</a>` or `blabla`? In other words, do you need the content of the elements as an XML string or just the text of the nested element?

Comment: I want the String "title" to contain "<a href="blabla">blabla</a>" and the String "text" to contain "<a href="123">123</a>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@XmlAnyElement` annotation is used as a catch-all for elements in the XML input that aren't mapped by name to some specific property. That's why there can be only one such annotation per class (including inherited properties). What you want is this:

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String text;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = TitleHandler.class)
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "text")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = TextHandler.class)
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

The `@XmlElement` annotation indicates that the corresponding property is mapped to elements with that name. So the Java `text` property derives from the XML `<text>` element, and the `title` property from the `<title>` element. Since the names of the properties and the elements are the same, this is also the default behavior without the `@XmlElement` annotations, so you could leave them out.

In order to handle the conversion from XML content to a String instead of an actual structure (like a `Title` class or `Text` class) you'll need an adapter. that's what the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is for. It specifies how marshalling/unmarshalling for that property must be handled.

See this useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341694/630136

An example of how you could implement `TitleHandler`.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class TitleHandler extends XmlAdapter<Object, String> {

    /**
     * Factory for building DOM documents.
     */
    private final DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory;
    /**
     * Factory for building transformers.
     */
    private final TransformerFactory transformerFactory;

    public TitleHandler() {
        docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        // The provided Object is a DOM Element
        Element titleElement = (Element) v;
        // Getting the "a" child elements
        NodeList anchorElements = titleElement.getElementsByTagName("a");
        // If there's none or multiple, return empty string
        if (anchorElements.getLength() != 1) {
            return "";
        }
        Element anchor = (Element) anchorElements.item(0);
        // Creating a DOMSource as input for the transformer
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(anchor);
        // Default transformer: identity tranformer (doesn't alter input)
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        // This is necessary to avoid the <?xml ...?> prolog
        transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
        // Transform to a StringWriter
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        // Returning result as string
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        // DOM document builder
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        // Creating a new empty document
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        // Creating the <title> element
        Element titleElement = doc.createElement("title");
        // Setting as the document root
        doc.appendChild(titleElement);
        // Creating a DOMResult as output for the transformer
        DOMResult result = new DOMResult(titleElement);
        // Default transformer: identity tranformer (doesn't alter input)
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        // String reader from the input and source
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(v);
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(stringReader);
        // Transforming input string to the DOM
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        // Return DOM root element (<title>) for JAXB marshalling to XML
        return doc.getDocumentElement();
    }

}
```

If the type for unmarshalling input/marshalling output is left as `Object`, JAXB will provide DOM nodes. The above uses XSLT transformations (though without an actual stylesheet, just an "identity" transform) to turn the DOM input into a String and vice-versa. I've tested it on a minimal input document and it works for both XML to an `Item` object and the other way around.

EDIT:

The following version will handle any XML content in `<title>` rather than expecting a single `<a>` element. You'll probably want to turn this into an abstract class and then have `TitleHander` and `TextHandler` extend it, so that the currently hardcoded `<title>` tags are provided by the implementation.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class TitleHandler extends XmlAdapter<Object, String> {

    /**
     * Factory for building DOM documents.
     */
    private final DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory;
    /**
     * Factory for building transformers.
     */
    private final TransformerFactory transformerFactory;

    /**
     * XSLT that will strip the root element. Used to only take the content of an element given
     */
    private final static String UNMARSHAL_XSLT = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n" +
"<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">\n" +
"\n" +
"    <xsl:output method=\"xml\" omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\" />\n" +
"\n" +
"    <xsl:template match=\"/*\">\n" +
"      <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>\n" +
"    </xsl:template>\n" +
"\n" +
"    <xsl:template match=\"@*|node()\">\n" +
"        <xsl:copy>\n" +
"            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>\n" +
"        </xsl:copy>\n" +
"    </xsl:template>\n" +
"    \n" +
"</xsl:transform>";

    public TitleHandler() {
        docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        // The provided Object is a DOM Element
        Element rootElement = (Element) v;
        // Creating a DOMSource as input for the transformer
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(rootElement);
        // Creating a transformer that will strip away the root element
        StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(UNMARSHAL_XSLT));
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
        // Transform to a StringWriter
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        // Returning result as string
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        // DOM document builder
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        // Creating a new empty document
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        // Creating a DOMResult as output for the transformer
        DOMResult result = new DOMResult(doc);
        // Default transformer: identity tranformer (doesn't alter input)
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        // String reader from the input and source
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("<title>" + v + "</title>");
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(stringReader);
        // Transforming input string to the DOM
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        // Return DOM root element for JAXB marshalling to XML
        return doc.getDocumentElement();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What if field "title" contains not only <a>, but somethink like this: "<a href="blabla">blabla</a><p>12345</p>Hello World<br/>"

Comment: OK, i found solutions

Comment: @DmitryIgumnov I've made an edit to show a version of the handler that deals with generic cases.