# How to get a value between tags with XML format using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb

I have a xml format like below:

```
<list>12
    <item name="a">
        <child parent="b" age="1">David Beckham</child>
    </item>
</list>
```

The question is how could i extract 12 using JAXB? Which annotation supports it? Thank a lot.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Usually you would acquire the inner text using the `@XmlValue` annotation, and the item element using `@XmlElement` annotation. However the two annotations are incompatible. Using both of them inside the same class generates a JAXB error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and you are right. If i declare list tag as a variable with annotation @XmlElement i could get that value. But i like to attract also the item object inside a list tag. So do we have any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @AhmadShahwan: could i ask more question? is above right xml format?

Comment: May be using `@XmlAdapter`. Please check  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341694/3402449).

Comment: This is a valid XML.

Comment: The <list> tag has a "mixed" content (elements and text), where "12" is text content.

Comment: @dimplex: do you have a better way?

Comment: Does this annotation @XmlMixed help in this case?

Comment: It is possible. Write an XML Schema for this and compile it with XJC.

Answer (score 2):

Following is the working example.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRefs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class TestJAXBMixed {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String str = 
            "<list>12<item name=\"a\"><child parent=\"b\" age=\"1\">David Beckham</child></item></list>";
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Child.class, Item.class, ListElement.class);
        final JAXBElement<ListElement> obj = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(str)), ListElement.class);
        // The following is an array of objects representing the <list> content in order, 
        // i.e. it is a sequence of a String (12) and an Object (Item)
        final List<Object> content = obj.getValue().getContent();
        System.out.println(content);
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name="child")
class Child {

    private String parent;
    private String age;
    private String text;

    public String getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="parent")
    public void setParent(String parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="age")
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="item")
class Item {

    private String name;
    private Child child;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="list")
class ListElement {

    private List<Object> content;

    public List<Object> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name="item", type=Item.class)
    })
    public void setContent(List<Object> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
 final String data = ...
 final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
 final Element element = simple.fromXml(data);
 System.out.println(element.text);
```

Will output:

```
12
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Actually i have solved the problem but it is good to know another way, thanks.