# Read XML body element having multiple values based on different requests

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xml-parsing, javaparser

I am parsing a `XML` request using `Java`. The `XML` structure is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestServices>
    <header>
        //Header Details
    </header>
    <body>
        <ele1>
            <ele2>
                <ele3>534159XXXXXX0176</ele3>  //Or ele_3, ele03, ele_03             
            </ele2>
        </ele1>
    </body>
</TestServices>
```

I have created classes for the same to read the Header and Body elements. Each node is a class and I am reading the **ele3** value like this.

```
String ele3 = testServicesRequest.getBody().getEle1().getEle2().getEle3();
```

The element name for **ele3** can be different based on different request. I have used **Generate Java class from xsd** feature in eclipse and it has generated classes like this.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "ele3"
})
public class ReqEle2 {
    @XmlElement(name = "ele3", required = true)
    protected String ele3;
    public String getEle3() {
        return ele3;
    }    
    public void setEle3(String value) {
        this.ele3 = value;
    }    
}
```

My requirement is simple. I just want to put multiple element names for single **getEle3()** method. eg. **ele_3, ele03, ele_03** using less code changes. Or Please suggest me any other efficient way to do that.

For now I am trying to do this like this which I think is not good.

```
public class ReqEle3 {

    @XmlElement(name = "ele03", required = true)
    protected String ele3_1="";

    @XmlElement(name = "ele_3", required = true)
    protected String ele3_2="";

    @XmlElement(name = "ele3", required = true)
    protected String ele3_3="";

    @XmlElement(name = "ele3_old", required = true)
    protected String ele3_4="";

    public String getEle3() {
        if(ele3_1 != null && !ele3_1.isEmpty()){            
            return ele3_1;  
        }        
        else if(ele3_2 != null && !ele3_2.isEmpty()){           
            return ele3_2;  
        }
        else if(ele3_3 != null && !ele3_3.isEmpty()){           
            return ele3_3;  
        }
        else if(ele3_4 != null && !ele3_4.isEmpty()){           
            return ele3_4;  
        }
        return "";
    }    
}
```

Comment: You can use method overriding

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan Did you mean method overloading?

Comment: no method overriding which is done in a child class

Comment: I mean this @XmlElement(name = "ele3", required = true) can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom deserialiser for `ele3` node. To be precise, custom deserialiser for `ele2` node because this is the last constant node. Below example contains only required part to understand the solution:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class JaxbApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ReqEle1.class);
        String xml0 = "<ele1><ele2><ele3>534159XXXXXX0176</ele3></ele2></ele1>";
        String xml1 = "<ele1><ele2><ele_3>534159XXXXXX0176</ele_3></ele2></ele1>";
        String xml2 = "<ele1><ele2><ele03>534159XXXXXX0176</ele03></ele2></ele1>";

        for (String xml : new String[]{xml0, xml1, xml2}) {
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            Object unmarshal = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(reader);
            System.out.println(unmarshal);
        }
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ele1")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"ele2"})
class ReqEle1 {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ReqEle2XmlAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name = "ele2", required = true)
    protected ReqEle2 ele2;

    // getters, setters
}

class ReqEle2XmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, ReqEle2> {

    @Override
    public ReqEle2 unmarshal(Object v) {
        Element element = (Element) v;
        ReqEle2 reqEle2 = new ReqEle2();
        reqEle2.setEle3(element.getFirstChild().getTextContent());

        return reqEle2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(ReqEle2 v) throws Exception {
        return null; // Implement if needed
    }
}

class ReqEle2 {

    protected String ele3;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Above code prints:

```
ReqEle1{ele2=ReqEle2{ele3='534159XXXXXX0176'}}
ReqEle1{ele2=ReqEle2{ele3='534159XXXXXX0176'}}
ReqEle1{ele2=ReqEle2{ele3='534159XXXXXX0176'}}
```

See also:

- [JAXB @XmlAdapter for arbitrary XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272059/jaxb-xmladapter-for-arbitrary-xml)