# Wrap with multiple XML tags without create diferent classes + Jackson + Java

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have a class like that:

```
class A {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "ErrorMessages")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ErrorMessage")
    List<String> errorMessages;

}
```

The output is:

```
<A>
    <ErrorMessages>
        <ErrorMessage>
            error1
        </ErrorMessage>

        <ErrorMessage>
            error2
        </ErrorMessage>

    </ErrorMessages>
</A>
```

but I want it to be like that

```
<A>
    <ErrorMessages>
        <ErrorMessages>
            <ErrorMessage>
                error1
            </ErrorMessage>
        </ErrorMessages>
        <ErrorMessages>
            <ErrorMessage>
                error2
            </ErrorMessage>
        </ErrorMessages>
    </ErrorMessages>
</A>
```

How can I achieve this with `Jackson`  without adding one more class?
Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [`XmlAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) to generate arbitrary XML for your `errorMessages` field (explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341694/2425232)).

E.g. annotate your class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
class A {

    @XmlElement(name = "ErrorMessages")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ErrorMessagesAdapter.class)
    List<String> errorMessages;

}
```

And implement your ErrorMessagesAdapter, for instance:

```
class ErrorMessagesAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, List<String>> {

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    public ErrorMessagesAdapter() {
        super();
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // TODO: Handle Exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(List<String> errorMessages) throws Exception {
        Document doc = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("ErrorMessages");

        for (String errorMessage : errorMessages) {
            Element wrapperElement = doc.createElement("ErrorMessages");
            Element errorMessageElement = doc.createElement("ErrorMessage");
            errorMessageElement.setTextContent(errorMessage);
            wrapperElement.appendChild(errorMessageElement);
            root.appendChild(wrapperElement);
        }

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        // TODO: implement unmarshalling
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<A>
  <ErrorMessages>
    <ErrorMessages>
      <ErrorMessage>error1</ErrorMessage>
    </ErrorMessages>
    <ErrorMessages>
      <ErrorMessage>error2</ErrorMessage>
    </ErrorMessages>
  </ErrorMessages>
</A>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to show another way to manipulate the serializing stage with a custom serializer on Jackson. I examined how the jackson serialize models and found the responsible class for `List<String>` class that is called `IndexedStringListSerializer`. It is described as `final` so I can't extend a new class from it. So, I have copied the whole content of the class and manipulate the correct position to get what you want. Maybe this way you don't want it, but it can be helpful for anybody.

I changed `JacksonXmlProperty` localName to `ErrorMessages` instead of ErrorMessage. Also, I added a custom `JacksonSerialize` annotation.

```java
class A {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "ErrorMessages")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ErrorMessages")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomListSerializer.class)
    List<String> errorMessages;
}
```

`CustomListSerializer` is copied from `IndexedStringListSerializer` content.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.WritableTypeId;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonFormatVisitors.JsonArrayFormatVisitor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonFormatVisitors.JsonFormatTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedStringListSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StaticListSerializerBase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * It is copied from {@link IndexedStringListSerializer} and changed.
 */
public class CustomListSerializer extends StaticListSerializerBase<List<String>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static CustomListSerializer instance = new CustomListSerializer();

    /*
    /**********************************************************
    /* Life-cycle
    /**********************************************************
     */

    protected CustomListSerializer() {
        super(List.class);
    }

    public CustomListSerializer(CustomListSerializer src,
                                       Boolean unwrapSingle) {
        super(src, unwrapSingle);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> _withResolved(BeanProperty prop, Boolean unwrapSingle) {
        return new CustomListSerializer(this, unwrapSingle);
    }

    @Override protected JsonNode contentSchema() { return createSchemaNode("string", true); }

    @Override
    protected void acceptContentVisitor(JsonArrayFormatVisitor visitor) throws JsonMappingException {
        visitor.itemsFormat(JsonFormatTypes.STRING);
    }

    /*
    /**********************************************************
    /* Actual serialization
    /**********************************************************
     */

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<String> value, JsonGenerator g,
                          SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException
    {
        final int len = value.size();
        if (len == 1) {
            if (((_unwrapSingle == null) &&
                    provider.isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED))
                    || (_unwrapSingle == Boolean.TRUE)) {
                serializeContents(value, g, provider, 1);
                return;
            }
        }
        g.writeStartArray(value, len);
        serializeContents(value, g, provider, len);
        g.writeEndArray();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(List<String> value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider provider,
                                  TypeSerializer typeSer)
            throws IOException
    {
        WritableTypeId typeIdDef = typeSer.writeTypePrefix(g,
                typeSer.typeId(value, JsonToken.START_ARRAY));
        g.setCurrentValue(value);
        serializeContents(value, g, provider, value.size());
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffix(g, typeIdDef);
    }

    private final void serializeContents(List<String> value, JsonGenerator g,
                                         SerializerProvider provider, int len) throws IOException
    {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            for (; i < len; ++i) {
                String str = value.get(i);
                if (str == null) {
                    provider.defaultSerializeNull(g);
                } else {
                    // CHANGE BEGIN
                    g.writeStartObject();
                    g.writeFieldName("ErrorMessage");
                    g.writeString(str);
                    g.writeEndObject();
                    // CHANGE END

                    // ORIGINAL BEGIN
                    // g.writeString(str);
                    // ORIGINAL END
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            wrapAndThrow(provider, e, value, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Example

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    A a = new A();
    a.errorMessages = Arrays.asList("error1", "error2");

    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(a);

    System.out.println(xml);
}
```

Output:

```
<A>
  <ErrorMessages>
    <ErrorMessages>
      <ErrorMessage>error1</ErrorMessage>
    </ErrorMessages>
    <ErrorMessages>
      <ErrorMessage>error2</ErrorMessage>
    </ErrorMessages>
  </ErrorMessages>
</A>
```